# Best way to search a string and return a conditional output in Julia?

Tags: string, julia

I am trying to write a simple BMI calculator in Julia using visual studio code. I want the program to first ask the user whether they prefer "metric" or "imperial" units, then tailor the follow-on questions based on the user's answer. Any suggestions on the best way to structure this? For example, I've tried:

```
println("Welcome, what is your name?")
user_name = readline(stdin)
println("Hello $user_name, nice to meet you.")

println("Please choose whether you would like to use metric or imperial units:"
preferred_units = readline(stdin)
function preference()
    if startswith(preferred_units, "imperial")
    println("Enter your weight in lbs:")
    weight_imperial = parse(Float64, deadline(stdin))
else
    if startswith(preferred_units, "metric")
    println("Enter your weight in kg:")
    weight_metric = parse(Float64, deadline(stdin))
end
```

Is there a different function that would be more appropriate here?

Comment: It goes beyond the scope of the question, but I would mention that it may be valuable to store the value together with the unit the user selected. The package Unitful.jl (https://painterqubits.github.io/Unitful.jl/stable/) can help you do that.

Comment: I'm so glad you mentioned that, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Your code errors for me because of a couple tiny typos/mistakes. This works for me:

```
println("Welcome, what is your name?")
user_name = readline(stdin)
println("Hello $user_name, nice to meet you.")

println("Please choose whether you would like to use metric or imperial units:")
preferred_units = readline(stdin)
function preference()
    if startswith(preferred_units, "imperial")
        println("Enter your weight in lbs:")
        weight_imperial = parse(Float64, readline(stdin))
    elseif startswith(preferred_units, "metric")
        println("Enter your weight in kg:")
        weight_metric = parse(Float64, readline(stdin))
    end 
end
preference()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was worried something was off with the way I was approaching the problem.